# ServiceStack Soap Retrieve Soap Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, servicestack

I need to extract a soap Header attribute from a incoming message to my service. I am using service stack and have been looking around and can't find a good answer anywhere. Can anyone tell me how to retrieve a SOAP Header Attribute from a request object?

Here is my service

```
public class NotificationServices : Service
{
    public GetAccountNotificationResponse Any (GetAccountNotification request)
    {
         //Do Some stuff Here!!!
         //Need to retrieve some header here
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. And if you know for a fact it can't be done please let me know as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) v3.9.49 you can access the Request SOAP Message (for SOAP Requests) using the `IHttpRequest.GetSoapMessage()` extension method, e.g:

```
public class NotificationServices : Service
{
    public GetAccountNotificationResponse Any (GetAccountNotification request)
    {
         //Do Some stuff Here!!!
         var requestSoapMessage = base.Request.GetSoapMessage();
    }
}
```

From the [Serialization / Deserialization wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream):

You can access raw WCF Message when accessed with the SOAP endpoints in your Service with `IHttpRequest.GetSoapMessage()` extension method, e.g:

```
Message requestMsg = base.Request.GetSoapMessage();
```

To tell ServiceStack to skip Deserializing the SOAP request entirely, add the `IRequiresSoapMessage` interface to your Request DTO, e.g:

```
public class RawWcfMessage : IRequiresSoapMessage {
    public Message Message { get; set; }
}

public object Post(RawWcfMessage request) { 
    request.Message... //Raw WCF SOAP Message
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this when I get back to work tomorrow :)

Comment: Is there a way to get a string representation of the whole message which i can save to a database for example to log it? I tried the .ToString() method but I'm getting weird some xmlReader exception.